# Vue apollo post Method

Tags: vue.js, apollo, vue-apollo

**Is posible to use only post method in vue apollo?**

We are using graphql and vue apollo plugin from cli, and I just want to use post method, is posible?

I have already conection but I just use post method.
I try fetchOptions: { method: "POST" }, but dont work*

these is my config

```
const defaultOptions = {
  // You can use `https` for secure connection (recommended in production)
  httpEndpoint,
  // You can use `wss` for secure connection (recommended in production)
  // Use `null` to disable subscriptions
  wsEndpoint: MyUrl,
  // LocalStorage token
  tokenName: AUTH_TOKEN,
  // Enable Automatic Query persisting with Apollo Engine
  persisting: false,
  // Use websockets for everything (no HTTP)
  // You need to pass a `wsEndpoint` for this to work
  websocketsOnly: false,
  // Is being rendered on the server?
  ssr: false,
}
};
```

Comment: `apollo-link-http`, assuming that's what's being used, should default to using POST for all requests. You can explicitly pass `useGETForQueries` to use GET (just for the queries), but this is not the default behavior.

Comment: thanks, daniel for these info.